# Variable in curly bracket double quote tcl

Tags: tcl

I am working this script I want script to replace the second line of my session.mvw file so I am asking input "name" if I enter 2222 as input I expect the second line of my session.mvw file as `{GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/222.rst"}`
but instead its only giving 
`{GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst"}`.

```
puts "Enter your name: "
#flush stdout set name [gets stdin]

    set in [open session.mvw r]

    # get the path to the parent directory
    set hostDir [file dirname session.mvw]
    set tempfile "$hostDir/temp2.txt"

    # open/create a temp file
    set out [open $tempfile w]
    set count 0

    while { [eof $in] != 1 } {
        gets $in line
        #set firstItem [lindex $line 0]   incr count
        # a match has been found...
        if {$count == 2 } {
            puts $out {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst"}
        } elseif {$count == 3} {
            puts $out {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst"}
            } else {
            puts $out $line 
            }
        }
    close $in
    close $out
    close $hostDir

    # over-write the existing file
    #file rename -force $tempfile session_file.mvw
```

Comment: Variable substitution will not happen inside braces. Change it to  `puts $out "GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = \"E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst\""`

Comment: but I want it exactly {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/222.rst"}         my next command depends on that I need braces so that the next hyperview software recognize that line

Comment: So how can I modify my script so that it will give '{GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/222.rst"}'   this as out put  with 222 as input

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's got a *general rule* that it doesn't do substitutions inside braces. That's usually exactly the right thing. However, in this case you need something a bit more. For these sorts of cases, there's the `subst` command which *does* do those **subst**itutions:

```
puts $out [subst {GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst"}]
```

(Note: If you're generating Tcl code with `subst`, you're probably doing it wrong. Not that this is what you're doing in this case, but still it's a warning to all readers…)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have braces around the value, you could do this

```
puts $out [list "GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = \"E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst\""]
```

or this

```
puts $out "{GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = \"E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/${name}.rst\"}"
```

both of which print the string

> `{GRAPHIC_FILE_1 = "E:/ge work/hyperview scripting/222.rst"}`